# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_getexif'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, attributeerror

I'm trying to extract information from my `Image`. First, I did:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open
('C:\Users\yujin\Desktop\유진 분량\1502635829917s')
```

The [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcCrr.jpg) was the information of my `Image`. Next, I did:

```
exif_data = image._getexif()

import PIL.ExifTags
exif = {
    PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]:v
    for k, v in image._getexif().items()
    if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS
}

print exif['GPSInfo']
```

Then I got this error:

> ```
> AttributeError
> Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-4-d491fd7796a9> in <module>()
> ----> 1 exif_data = image._getexif()
>       2
>       3 import PIL.ExifTags
>       4 exif = {
>       5     PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]:v
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_getexif'

I don't know where I did wrong.

Sorry for my ignorance about this site's rules at first. I didn't know how to format code on this page. My apologies!

## Update

I put this on one line:

```
image = Image.open('C:\Users\yujin\Desktop\유진 분량\1502635829917s')
```

Then I got a new error:

> ```
> IOError
> Traceback
> <ipython-input-17-1d98beb4f253> in <module>()
>       1 from PIL import Image
> ----> 2 image = Image.open('C:\Users\yujin\Desktop\Happy\2017-06-06-12-24-45‌​')
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.pyc in open(fp, mode) 2475 2476 if filename: -> 2477 fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb") 2478 exclusive_fp = True 2479
> ```
>
> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\Users\yujin\Desktop\Happy\x817-06-06-12-24-45'

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215380/trouble-accessing-exif-information-with-pil-image-getexif

Comment: @Flika205 Not a duplicate, but a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be on one line:

```
image = Image.open('C:\Users\yujin\Desktop\x.JPG')
```

What's happening now is that `image` is defined as `Image.open` and you are simply evaluating `('C:\Users\yujin\Desktop\x.JPG')` on a different line, so you get back the string in `Out[10]`.

Clearly, the `open` function will not have the attribute `_getexif`, so you get that `AttributeError`.