# Python3 - CSV Writer Sort by Date

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, writer

I have some problems creating a Python script and hope that you can help me.

The script should read the exif information (date, time and GPSInfo) from multiple images and write the results sorted by date into a CSV file.

Currently I manage to write the data into the CSV file. But I don't manage to sort the entries by date.

```
# for every file in the directory get the latlng
for file in os.listdir("/path/"):
    if file.endswith(".jpg" or ".png"):
        path_name = '/path'+ file
        meta_data =  ImageMetaData(path_name)
        latlng =meta_data.get_lat_lng()
        date = meta_data.date
        print(latlng, date)
        with open('dez.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            for x in range(0, 10):
                spamwriter.writerow(latlng)
                spamwriter.writerow(date)
```

Comment: Just so you know, you should've done `writer.writerow([date, latlng])`. Your code as it is now just writes a string that contains both as a single csv column.

Comment: Is pandas something you can use, its so nice for situations like these

Comment: @oppressionslayer how does your comment help him?

Comment: Your code is wrong `file.endswith(".jpg" or ".png")` will do `".jpg" or ".png"` first, which will evaluate to `True` so your code is doing `if file.endswith(True)` which will raise a `TypeError`. The code you ran to get the result is not the same one you pasted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you don't want the actual date in the output CSV, you should build a dictionary mapping `date`s to `lat_lng` pairs, sort the keys of the dict and *then* write each value of the dict to a CSV.

```
from pathlib import Path

IMAGE_DIRECTORY = Path("/home/user/Schreibtisch/recoveredPictures/")

images = list(IMAGE_DIRECTORY.glob("*.jpg")) + list(IMAGE_DIRECTORY.glob("*.png"))

date_to_lat_lng = {}
for image in images:
    meta_data = ImageMetaData(path_name)
    lat_lng = meta_data.get_lat_lng()
    date = meta_data.get_date_time()
    date_to_lat_lng[date] = [lat_lng[0], lat_lng[1]]

with open("test.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for date in sorted(date_to_lat_lng):
        writer.writerow(date_to_lat_lng[date])
```

(Updated with all the changes you asked for in the comments)

Comment: Hi, Boris,

thanks for your response.
It works so far.

I would like to sort the content but only write the coordinates and some strings into the file test.csv and not the date.

Content the test.csv should have:
latlng String1 String2 

Do you have a solution or a tip on how to implement this?

Comment: Change `data_and_latlng = []` into a dictionary mapping dates to the list of strings you want to write for that date (ie `data_to_latlng = {}`), change the `append` line to `date_to_latlng[date] = [latlng, "some string", "some other string"]` then instead of `writerows` do `for date in sorted(date_to_latlng): writer.writerow(date_to_latlng[key])`

Comment: Hi Boris, thanks again for your answer. My Code looks like this: 

date_to_latlng = {}
for image in images:
    meta_data = ImageMetaData(image)
    latlng = meta_data.get_lat_lng()
    date = meta_data.get_date_time()
    date_to_latlng[date] = [latlng, "some string", "some other string"]

with open("test.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for date in sorted(date_to_latlng):
        writer.writerow(date_to_latlng[latlng])

Comment: Unfortunately I can't write only the coordinates (which are sorted by date) into the file test.csv.
The coordinates should be sorted by date and written to the file test.csv, even if the date is not contained in the file test.csv.

The file test.csv should contain only the coordinates and then some strings:

Contents test.csv example:
49.195660595 -122.5059605950 String1 String2

Do you have any tips on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `writer.writerow(date_to_latlng[latlng])` should be `writer.writerow(date_to_latlng[date])`

Comment: Hi Boris, thanks again for your response. You're a big help.

I have one more question. At the moment the output looks like this:

```
`"(52.59504, -126.17413)", some string, other string, 2`
`"(43.05749, -121.72245)", some string, other string, 1`

```

But I want the output to look like this:


`52.59504 -126.17413 some string other string 1`
`43.05749 -121.72245 some string other string 2`


Each entry in the test.csv file should have an ascending numbering at the end. Furthermore, the , Comma (behind der first decimal value) and the brackets () should be deleted

Comment: All rows in the file test.csv should be delimited by a Tab "\t".

Comment: Change `date_to_latlng[date] = [latlng, "some string", "some other string"]` to `date_to_latlng[date] = [latlng[0], latlng[1],  "some string", "some other string"]` and change `delimeter=","` to `delimeter="\t"`

Comment: any idea how I can use the skript for PNG Files? I get the following error: PngImageFile' object has no attribute '_getexif'

Comment: @Blank95 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215380/trouble-accessing-exif-information-with-pil-image-getexif